What product markings/stampings indicate plywood that has been treated for ground-contact use in the US?
What product markings/stampings indicate plywood that has been treated for ground-contact use in the US?  I'm not sure that what has been delivered to me is what I asked for.   Mine says "Exposure 1" and "555" and "PS 1-19".

On the way to check out similar product on the shelves at another retailer, I received a callback from a plywood industry organization. The rep said the markings are from the original manufacturer of the plywood and that the pressure treatment is done afterwards, often by another company, and that not all pressure treated wood is marked with stamps indicating the PT grade. He referred me on to the AWPA, the American Wood Protection Association.
It turns out, what I bought is "ground contact general use" using micronized copper azole compounds, according to a small stapled sticker on each panel. They were behind a large adhesive label identifying my order/shipment.
